# Dart, replace a word and everything after, up to the first alphanumeric character

Tags: string, dart, replace, regexp-replace

in dart I would like in a string to replace the word "hi" (both upper and lower case) and everything after that, up to the first alphanumeric character.

For example:

```
String text = "How are you ? Hi , I am fine . "
// or
String text = "How are you ? hi! I am fine . "
```

must become:

```
String text = "How are you ? I am fine . "
```

*Thank you!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dart
String replaceFromWordToNextWord(
    String input, String word, String replacement) {
  var re = RegExp("\\b${RegExp.escape(word)}\\b[^a-z\\d]+", 
      caseSensitive: false);
  return input.replaceFirst(re, replacement);
}
```

On your text, it does:

```dart
void main() {
  var input = "How are you ? Hi , I am fine . ";
  print(replaceFromWordToNextWord(input, "hi", "")); 
  // Prints "How are you ? I am fine ."
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove that specific part, you can use a capture group `(\s|^)` to capture either the start of the string or a whitespace chars.

Then match either `Hi` or `hi` followed by any character except alphanumerics.

```
(\s|^)[hH]i[^a-zA-Z0-9]*
```

In the replacement use the first capture group.

```
void main() {
    String s = """How are you ? Hi , I am fine . 
How are you ? hi! I am fine . 
hi! I am fine . """;
    var pattern = RegExp(r"(\s|^)[hH]i[^a-zA-Z0-9]*");
    print(s.replaceAllMapped(pattern, (match) => '${match.group(1)}'));
}
```

Output

```
How are you ? I am fine . 
How are you ? I am fine . 
I am fine .
```

See a [Dart demo](https://tio.run/##XY5PS8NAFMTP3U8xXYTsShP0qKWVHoR48KI3awuPZk0eJNnlZVv/1H72uIiXepwZ5jdTkcRx5C54iciqpG7ZZ3MFdfBcoSPujcVRTZ6jcF9jwAJa69K/g8Th0@9xh5IxwwOowxv3DgXUed7w9Dz@byTiXE0OJAgUo5M@rTy5@v4jGNHmdfje2nVTbni9pfxrlb9c5TebS21TJ6RX0QyFuNDSzq3a9pFCcJX5A81gOoq7xmKxRHZx/BVFLX4fzLU9ZTZBTuP4Aw) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/y2rzDy/1)..